# segmentation fault in recursive binary searching

Tags: c++

I want to binary search more than once using the same function but it's showing segmentation fault. For one input its giving correct answer but when I am giving multiple input for binary search(i.e, q>1 acc. to my code) then its showing segmentation fault.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int binarySearch(int x[],int l, int r, long int m ){
    if(r>=1){
        int mid=(r-1)/2+l;
        if (x[mid]==m) return mid;
        if (x[mid]>m) return binarySearch(x,l,mid-1,m);
        if (x[mid]<m) return binarySearch(x,mid+1,r,m);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    int n,q;
    cin>>n;
    int x[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){cin>>x[i];}
    int t = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);
    sort(x,x+t);
    cin>>q;
    while (q--){
        long int m;
        cin>>m;
        cout<<binarySearch(x,0,t-1,m)<<endl;
        
    }
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obligatory [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3282436) and [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3282436)

Comment: use `std::lower_bound` instead of implementing binary search yourself.

Comment: `int x[n];` is not standard C++.

Comment: `int mid=(r-1)/2+l;` can not be correct.

Comment: And one of the reasons for the above is a sufficiently large `n`, and that can be a few thousand on some systems, will blow the <expletive deleted> out of the stack.

Comment: `int t = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);` This is a very strange thing to do, given that you have used `n` right in the previous line.

Comment: What do you want your function to return when the element is not found?

Comment: Side note: When you have a consistent crash, see if you can reproduce it in a debug build. If you can, then narrowing down the cause, or even zoom right in on it, with a debugger is almost child's play. Run the program in the debugger. Wait for the crash. Investigate the the variables involved and the backtrace so see how you got there. Use the information gathered to improve your test cases and decide where to look next.

Comment: @Rishav Kumar There is a typo in this if statement if(r>=1){ there shall be if(r>=l){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The condtion `r>=1` should be `r-l+1>=1` to check if there are some element in the range.
- The initialization `int mid=(r-1)/2+l;` should be `int mid=(r-l)/2+l;` to correctly calculate the middle element.
- Variable-Length Array `int x[n];` is not in the standard C++. You should use heap allication `int *x = new int[n];` instead. After that, `n` should be used for the initialization of `t` because the technique to obtain the number of elements in arrays won't work with pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int binarySearch(int x[],int l, int r, long int m ){
    if(r-l+1>=1){
        int mid=(r-l)/2+l;
        if (x[mid]==m) return mid;
        if (x[mid]>m) return binarySearch(x,l,mid-1,m);
        if (x[mid]<m) return binarySearch(x,mid+1,r,m);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    int n,q;
    cin>>n;
    int *x = new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){cin>>x[i];}
    int t = n;
    sort(x,x+t);
    cin>>q;
    while (q--){
        long int m;
        cin>>m;
        cout<<binarySearch(x,0,t-1,m)<<endl;
        
    }
    
    
    delete[] x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Addendum: if allowed by the assignment, replacing `int *x = new int[n];` with `std::vector<int> x(n);` to simplify the memory management can be very attractive.  Using `std::vector` as your first choice for a dynamically sized array is highly recommended.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree, and `binarySearch(x,0,t-1,m)` should be `binarySearch(x.data(),0,t-1,m)` in that case.